# Get AD User based on their User Profile Description in a Specific AD Group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, group, where-object

I'm trying to get all AD users in the AD group 'Fall 2021' where the description is like 'Customer.' I'm currently receiving this error when I run my script. Any help or guidance is much appriciated.

```
Get-ADGroup : Error parsing query: 'Fall 2021' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '1'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADGroup -filter "Fall 2021" | Where-Objec ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADGroup], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroup
```

Here is the script:

```
Get-ADGroup -filter "Fall 2021" | Where-Object {$_.Description -like 'Customer' }
```

Comment: Replace `Get-ADGroup -filter "Fall 2021"` with `Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Fall 2021" |Get-ADUser -Properties description`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Filter "Fall 2021"` is not a valid syntax for the [AD Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)), if the **Name** of the group is `Fall 2021` you can use the `-Identity` parameter as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) points out. If you want to query the group membership, you can use [`Get-ADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps), or you can query the `Member` attribute of the group:

```sh
(Get-ADGroup -Identity 'Fall 2021' -Properties Member).Member | ForEach-Object {
    $obj = Get-ADObject $_ -Properties Description
    # if this member is a user object and it's description is customer
    if($obj.ObjectClass -eq 'user' -and $obj.Description -eq 'Customer') {
        # output this object
        $obj
    }
}
```

This query can be also reversed, we can use [`LDAPFilter`](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) to search for all users whose `MemerOf` attribute contains the `DistinguishedName` of the **Fall 2021** group and whose `Description` attribute is equal to **Customer**:

```sh
$groupDN = (Get-ADGroup -Identity 'Fall 2021').DistinguishedName
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(&(memberof=$groupDN)(description=Customer))"
```